# Settings Model to read multiple settings files and writes to one

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I am writing a Model to read, write and store settings.
I think my code is pretty good, but I am not 100% sure.
Any advice on how I could possibly improve it is welcome.

```
import ntpath

import yaml


class Settings:
    def __init__(self, paths=None, default_path=None):
        """Load, write and store settings

        This model manages setting files (YAML).

        Keyword Arguments:
            paths {list or None} -- list of full or relative
                                    paths with filenames (default: {None})
            default_path {str or None} -- path to user settings, read last
                                          and default for writing
                                          (default: {None})
        """
        paths = paths or []
        # Make sure paths are unique and sorted by file name
        self.paths = sorted(set(paths), key=lambda p: ntpath.basename(p))
        # Remove default_path from paths (look at next comment)
        try:
            self.paths.remove(default_path)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        # Readd default_path at the end to make sure it's loaded last
        if default_path is not None:
            self.paths.append(default_path)
        # Set remaining attributes
        self.default_path = default_path
        self.settings = {}

        # Load files
        self.reload()

    def reload(self):
        """Reload files into buffer

        Reloads the files specified in self.paths
        and writes them into the buffer.
        """
        # Clear settings to ensure no unwanted leftovers
        self.settings.clear()
        # Load every path (sorted by filename, self.default_path last)
        for path in self.paths:
            with open(path, 'r') as f:
                content = f.read()
            self.settings.update(yaml.load(content) or {})

    def write(self, key, value, path=None):
        """Write into file

        Writes key and value into the file specified
        by path (or self.default_path if None)

        Arguments:
            key {immutable} -- key to use (valid YAML key)
            value {ANY} -- value to save

        Keyword Arguments:
            path {str} -- path to save file (default: {None})
        """
        path = path or self.default_path
        assert path is not None

        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            settings = yaml.load(f.read()) or {}

        settings[key] = value
        self.settings[key] = value

        with open(path, 'w') as f:
            f.write(yaml.dump(settings, default_flow_style=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

The module should import `os.path` instead of `ntpath`.

`os.path` is the cross-platform equivalent of `ntpath`, it automatically picks the appropriate path module for the OS your code is running on. So it will use `ntpath` behind the scenes when running on Windows, but you will also be able to use the code on more operating systems than just Windows.  (See the note at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Comment: Thank you, I did it that way initially but changed it after reading the accepted answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/python-extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format; Seems as he was wrong?

Comment: @Matthias: That post is dealing with Windows paths specifically. If you must deal with Windows paths, use `ntpath`; if you are dealing with whatever paths are used by the OS your program is run on, use `os.path`.  You shouldn't be dealing with only Windows paths because you try to open the files.  On Linux, you can't open Windows files.  Therefore, you should be using `os.path`

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found so far is to either rename the attribute "settings" to "buffer" (or something similar), or to make Settings inherit from dict (or better from collections.MutableMapping as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/python-how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict)).
Doing something like this is awkward:

```
settings_instance.settings['test_key']
```